# so much loading while access another form with crystal report using mdi form

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, mdi

Accessing another form with crystal report using MDIParent form is too much loading, it consumed almost 20 to 30 secs before it shows. Here is my sample code on accessing form with Crystal Report.

```
Dim bsm As New billing_main()
bsm.MdiParent = Me
bsm.Show()
```

Can any one show another way to access other form?

Comment: 1) The problem is most likely with the code being run on `load` event of `billing_main` 2) There may be too many records being loaded into the report from the database or un-optimized records, use of too many expressions, formulas etc. 3) Another possibility, Crystal Reports usually take longer time to load when run first time after application start

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @haraman, now i know the main reason it cause much log